# Array of viewed posts begins with a comma

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress

I have the following function to store an array of viewed post IDs. It all works, but the stored array always begins with a comma- `, xxxx` - I assume it's because i'm imploding an empty array?

```
function workshop_save_viewed_enquiries() {

    global $current_user;
    wp_get_current_user();

    if ( is_singular( 'enquiry' ) && in_array( 'workshop', (array) $current_user->roles ) ) {

        $viewed_enquiries_array = explode( ", ", get_user_meta( $current_user->ID, 'wpcf-viewed-enquiries', true ) );

        if ( !in_array( get_the_ID(), $viewed_enquiries_array ) ){

            $viewed_enquiries_array[] = get_the_ID();
            $viewed_enquiries = implode(', ', $viewed_enquiries_array ); 
            update_user_meta( $current_user->ID, 'wpcf-viewed-enquiries', $viewed_enquiries );

        }

    }

}
add_action( "wp_footer", "workshop_save_viewed_enquiries" );
```

Comment: No, imploding an empty array would only get you an empty string as a result. // You should not do your own im- and exploding here to begin with; if you have to store multiple values into a meta data field in WordPress, then you should do that using PHP’s `serialize` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a small change to see if the data exists and added extra data with a callback array, but you could pass a direct array that the update_user_meta function will already work;)

```
function workshop_save_viewed_enquiries() {

    global $current_user;
    wp_get_current_user();

    if ( is_singular( 'enquiry' ) && in_array( 'workshop', (array) $current_user->roles ) || true == true ) {

        $viewed_enquiries_array = get_user_meta( $current_user->ID, 'wpcf-viewed-enquiries', true );
        if( $viewed_enquiries_array ){
            $viewed_enquiries_array = explode(', ', $viewed_enquiries_array );
        }else{
            $viewed_enquiries_array = array();
        }

        if ( !in_array( get_the_ID(), $viewed_enquiries_array ) ){

            $viewed_enquiries_array[] = get_the_ID();
            $viewed_enquiries = implode(', ', $viewed_enquiries_array ); 
            update_user_meta( $current_user->ID, 'wpcf-viewed-enquiries', $viewed_enquiries );

        }

    }

}
add_action( "wp_footer", "workshop_save_viewed_enquiries" );
```